# Horizontal collection view with different height of cells

Tags: swift, collectionview

I am trying to do some horizontal collection view with dynamic height of each cell. Like citymapper does when you have aready choosen a trip. ¿Has anyone got any idea of how to do this? Even though if it's not with a collection view.

[Video of the behaviour](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JOBHlLblqewA_JI2Y4-ig4wk4m7mHnnF/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is implementing the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` of the collectionView.

One of the methods of this delegate is `final public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize`. Here you can return the size of the collectionCell depending on the content or whatever you use to determinate the height.

Hope it helps.

Comment: But in an horizontal collection view, each cell can have a different height? If so, how can i set the collectionview via storyboard without fixing its height with a constraint?

Comment: @Andrea Yes, I guess you could have different heights. One way of doing this is setting a max height to your collection view, that you know no cell is gonna be higher?

Comment: but the view of behind must be interactive too. So the smaller ones wont let the map to be interactive

Comment: @Andrea Ok I understand, maybe you could pre-calculate the height of each item and also adjust the height constraint of the collection in some of the uiscrollview delegate methods. Don't know if that would work.

Comment: @Andrea you should post your code to be able to help you.